# how to select content from 2 tables based on id that are in both tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 tables collected and request, when a request is made it create an id, when the person get part of total amount it goes to collected tabled along with the loan id, i need to echo request info along with collected info based on loan_id that located on both tables then fetch this on php.

table request
[image]

tabled collected
[image]

```
select * from request, users 
where request.user_id = users.id and request.user_id = $user_id"
```

this select gets the request table

```
select * from collected where loan_id = 146 (loan_id from request table)
```

i will like to have request info along with collected table info corresponding to each loan id from request table

Comment: All the `print`s you got there and the `while` (and basically all the PHP code) is **not** relevant to your question. Please clear the code and keep **only** whats relevant (which is the actual query you send).

Comment: i edited my question, i set php because in the end i need to echo all info

Comment: Now your question is much better. Got my vote here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Join (inner join if the table column always match)

```
select * 
from request 
inner join collected on request.loan_id = collected.loan_id
inner join users on  request.user_id = users.id
Where request.user_id = $user_id
```

or left join if the column  sometime don't  match

```
select * 
from request 
left join collected on request.loan_id = collected.loan_id
inner join users on  request.user_id = users.id
Where request.user_id = $user_id
```

Comment: i used the 1 option which actually output what i need, but request table display 3 times the same info and collected is accurate which makes sense because it has 3 submit with loan id 147, is there a way to display request info 1 line collected info 3(info) lines or more depending on the amount to is 1 to more

Comment: if the 3 rows are exactly the same you can use select distinct .. if not you must select disctinct  with explicit column name instead of  select *

Comment: i mean request info i need it all. collected table just a few example collected amount and collect date are info that i need. i will like output 1 to more, 2 to more, 3 to more and so on

Comment: @walteralexander   .i suggest you of  post a new specific question with  some data sample and the explected  result  .. (don't use  image .. post proper data instead)  eventually comment me the new link